# Where is f2mma.zip, Fortran to Mathematica converter?

Tags: packages, fortran

I want to convert the [SOFA](http://www.iausofa.org/) libraries to 
*Mathematica*, and found out about f2mma, a Fortran to *Mathematica* 
converter.

Google points to many papers about f2mma, but the only [link to the 
software](http://sirius.ihep.su/~siver/f2mma.zip) itself is broken (and 
http://sirius.ihep.su/ confirms that the server is mostly gone).

Where can I get a copy of this useful tool?

Comment: Before anyone else tries it out: the Wayback Machine was not able to save a copy of the sought *.zip file. :(

Comment: I guess you will have to write to the author. Since his email server is also gone, hopefully he will still be responding to his Gmail account.

Comment: I found this page, it seems that it contains some encoded files by that author: http://grokbase.com/t/perl/recdescent/046tf9acv1/problems-with-precompiling-parser

Comment: Were you able to find the files? If so, it would be very much appreciated if you could repost them here, if Andrey S. Siver is agreeable to that.